How do Thomists understand the efficient and final causes in planetary motion under Newtonian physics?
Under the influence of Newtonian physics Thomists have come to perceive the force of inertia and the force of gravity as the efficient cause of the planetary motion confining the final cause to things like orderliness in creation.
But there is an alternative explanation seemingly better suited to the way Thomas Aquinas might have explained it. Perhaps the mathematics of Newtonian physics is the final cause: the mathematical spectacle to be achieved. The efficient cause is simply the work of angels who are excellent mathematicians and communicators working together to move all the particles in the solar system so as to orchestrate a mathematically precise show.

It is doubtful that pushing particles according to rote calculations is work befitting angels. God can easily make it happen without their involvement, but that is more deism than Thomism, see Clockwork universe. Aristotle says in  Physics II.2:"But the nature is the end or 'that for the sake of which'. For if a thing undergoes a continuous change and there is a stage which is last, this stage is the end or 'that for the sake of which'." So the final cause of all this math is what it is set to bring about in the end.

@Conifold Angels are actually fitting for this role within Thomism, and the forces of inertia and gravity are better understood as formal causes rather than efficient causes: https://chatgpt.com/share/9f92b572-ed6a-481b-aa93-e7c3d2928811

The final cause is the what-it-is-to-be-accomplished. The mathematical formula of Newton is an approximation of observable measurements; the mathematics have been refined/extended in general relativity. A final cause cannot be equalised with a mathematical formula, because a formula cannot account for everything; instead a final cause can. For example in quantum physics, in order for the formula to account for the observable results, it became a probability. You could ascribe to the probability formula an ontological representation of reality (in the sense of a final cause), but still again  you have to explain what that probability really means. No one knows how exactly things work, whether it's the angels, a Newtonian force, or a field of gravity; even the concept of inertia has a totally different meaning in Newtonian physics vs general relativity. We generally think that logic/science can shed light on the efficient causes, but there always seems that there is something missing: the final cause, an inexplicable force that governs the way in which things and phenomena evolve.

Thank you. I tried to make sense of your answer by talking to my Thomas Aquinas Emulator: https://chatgpt.com/share/f91e248b-d062-4e86-8323-ea0605173ac0

@MichalRyszardWojcik, so, which part is unclear to you?

There is nothing clear to me in your answer. The question is about the four kinds of causes in Newtonian physics under Thomism. The escapade into general relativity is only confusing. I do not ask about the truth as best understood by you, but I ask to understand concepts within certain frameworks. The link I included explains how I perceive the question.
